# UDF using Java methods breaks on spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have done this code on databricks environment but when I try it on my local env it breaks...

```
  val _event_day_of_week = (event_date_of_event: String) => {
    import java.time.LocalDate
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

    val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val dayOfWeek: String = LocalDate.parse(event_date_of_event.substring(0,10), formatter).getDayOfWeek.toString
    dayOfWeek
  }

  val event_day_of_weekUDF = udf(_event_day_of_week)

df.select($"uuid", event_day_of_weekUDF($"event_date_of_event") as "event_day_of_week").first
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.faniak.ml.eventBuzz$.delayedEndpoint$com$faniak$ml$eventBuzz$1(eventBuzz.scala:72)
    at com.faniak.ml.eventBuzz$delayedInit$body.apply(eventBuzz.scala:17)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.faniak.ml.eventBuzz$.main(eventBuzz.scala:17)
    at com.faniak.ml.eventBuzz.main(eventBuzz.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

version is Spark 2.1

Comment: Does your Main class extend App instead of using a main method?  That's known to cause problems with spark.     Also your function doesn't do any null checking, make sure you don't have any nulls in that column.

Comment: Related: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)

Comment: @puhlen Hi, yes it extends App. Are you saying that it is the problem?
Regarding the nulls I have none.

Comment: @puhlen Thanks, it was a problem due to extend App class...

Comment: @carlosrodrigues What exactly was the problem? Can you describe it and approve as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the UDFs. When prototyping on Apache Spark, do not extend the Scala class App because it does not work properly with Spark.

```
object EventBuzzDataset extends App {
```

In order to make it work you should write:

```
object EventBuzzDataset{

   def main(args: Array[String])
```

The problem is well detailed here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4170
and
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3497

Thanks to @puhlen for the hint!